# python logging to multiple destination

Tags: python, logging

I am new to Python. I now need to make use of logging and here is the experiment I did:

I have 2 files:

logtest_1.py, logtest_2.py

logtest_1.py:

```
    import logging
    from logtest_2 import loglib

    format = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=format,level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Before calling loglib...')
    loglib()
    logger.info('Loglib done.')
```

logtest_2.py:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
    import time

```
def loglib():
    logger_2 = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger_3 = logging.getLogger('TimeRotateLogger')
    logger_3.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('timerotate.log',
                                        when='s',
                                        interval=2,
                                        backupCount=10)
    logger_3.addHandler(handler)

    logger_2.info('This is a log from logtest_2.')

    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(5):
        logger_3.info('Rotation test...')
        time.sleep(2)
```

I try to use `logger_3` to write info to those time rotation files. Actually, this works. However, it also prints out to the screen:

```
2015-02-16 15:26:34,010: INFO: Before calling loglib...
2015-02-16 15:26:34,011: INFO: This is a log from logtest_2.
2015-02-16 15:26:35,019: INFO: Rotation test...
2015-02-16 15:26:37,029: INFO: Rotation test...
2015-02-16 15:26:39,039: INFO: Rotation test...
2015-02-16 15:26:41,049: INFO: Rotation test...
2015-02-16 15:26:43,059: INFO: Rotation test...
2015-02-16 15:26:45,070: INFO: Loglib done.
```

I only want logger_3 to log into those files. How can I prevent it from printing to the screen?

Also, why this is happening? I've already given the handler to logger_3 which writes to files.

If I really want to keep `logging.basicConfig(format=format,level=logging.DEBUG)` in the logtest_1.py, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your `logger_3` by default also [propagates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) log events to its parent logger, the root logger.

If you use [`basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), the root logger will have a `StreamHandler` attached to it by default which causes your message to also end up on the console.

To prevent this, you can either set `logger_3.propagate = False`, or only attach handlers directly to your root logger (which is the most common used setup) and use [logging levels](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setLevel) and [filters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects) to control where your output goes.

---

An example for only attaching your handlers to the root logger could look like this:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


format = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('timerotate.log',
                                   when='s',
                                   interval=2,
                                   backupCount=10)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.root.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('This will end up on console and in timerotate.log')
logger.debug('This will only end up in timerotate.log')
```

`basicInfo()` attaches a `StreamHandler` with level `INFO` to the root logger that logs to `stdout` - but only messages with level [`INFO` or higher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#levels).

You then attach a second handler with level `DEBUG`, so it will log every message with level `DEBUG` or higher to `timerotate.log`. This is a very simple example that uses different log levels to determine where output ends up - using this approach you can't send a particular statement *only* to the console, and a different one *only* to a file.

If you need more fine grained control, you could for example pass some data in the [`extra` keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) when logging, and [add a filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.addFilter) to any of your handlers to only emit messages that match certain criteria.

But, if you simply want to be able to directly control from your code that a particular message should go to a file, and only that file, then it's probably easiest to simply set `logger_3.propagate` to `False`, and use the setup you already described.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Also, could you show me a example of 'only attach handlers directly to your root logger' method?

Answer (score 1):

See [`Logger.propagate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate).  Set this to `False` on your submodule loggers to prevent messages logged to them from bubbling up to your root logger as well.